# UPPAAL- Generate some strategy

Tags: uppaal

I have been using Uppaal Stratego for some time now. I have generate strategies using verifyta cli and used command like --print-strategies pathtoShowStrategy file.
Now my strategy produced is of 416.56 Mb text file.

I have used --generate-strategy O to generate some strategies and also to get the printed result in a folder. Below is what I used in cli. My machine is Linux 64bit ( if in any case is need)

pathToVerifyta/verifyta --print-strategies folderlocation/ --generate-strategy 0 pathToModelLocation.

The output text file seems so as huge as the original one ie file is of same size. I also tried reversing the --print-strategies and --generate-strategy but doesnot help much. Can somebody please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what your question is, but a number of usage-examples are given in a recent repeatability package:
https://zenodo.org/record/3268381

Strategies are inherently large as they refer to the entire state space - and the current textual output format is not compact either.

If you are looking for a way to parse (learned) strategies, take a look at https://github.com/DEIS-Tools/libstrategy/

Comment: I am not looking any tool/code to understand the strategy file . My question was more to generate some of the strategy using verifyta cli.That didnot answer my question

Comment: Strategies are generated from a specific query.
To provide one, you can either modify the query-part of the model-xml file, or provide a standalone q-file, for example:

./bin-Linux/verifyta --print-strategies simple-stratego.xml simple-stratego.q

where simple-stratego.q contains
strategy SAFE = control: A[] !Process.BAD

Comment: You are right but to generate some strategies eg  pathtoverifyta.bin --generate-strategy 0 pathToxmlfilewith query --print-strategies to a folder location to generate the file.  Sadly again, peter-gjøl-jensen you haven't answered my question!! I would request to read the question.

Comment: @Satarupa, can you then clarify exactly what your question is? It is unclear to me - if my answers above did not help you.